# Error in SaaS routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am developing SaaS app and in routes i have following code

```
$subdomain = '';
$domain_parts = explode('.', Request::server('HTTP_HOST'));
if (count($domain_parts) == 3) {
$subdomain = $domain_parts[0];

    if ($subdomain == 'www') {
      $subdomain = '';
    } 
}
if (empty($subdomain)) {
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@showIntro');
} else {

Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.'.Config::get('app.domain'), 'before' => 'db.setup'), function() {
          {
    Route::get('/', array(
        'as' => 'login',
        'uses' => 'LoginController@showLoginForm'
    ));
    Route::post('login', array(
        'as' => 'performLogin',
        'uses' => 'LoginController@performLogin'
    ));
    Route::get('logout', array(
        'as' => 'logout',
        'uses' => 'LoginController@performLogout'
    ));
});
```

The problem is if subdomain is exists then it will not redirecting to login page. If i remove the content of the array in `Route::group`
then it will work but the array content is neccesarry, The error i am getting is `NotFoundHttpException`i know there is a small mistake but not getting that, So any solution for this route error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your evaluation here is actually not necessary:

```
$subdomain = '';

$domain_parts = explode('.', Request::server('HTTP_HOST'));
if (count($domain_parts) == 3) {
$subdomain = $domain_parts[0];

    if ($subdomain == 'www') {
      $subdomain = '';
    } 
}
if (empty($subdomain)) {
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@showIntro');
} else {
```

You can get rid of this code, and then simply put
 `Route::get('/', 'IndexController@showIntro');` 
after the `Route::group()` for subdomain.

I do something like this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.' . Config::get('database.environment_url') .'') , function()
{
   //  Subdomain-only activity here.
}

// If there is no subdomain, Laravel will go straight to this route first.
Route::get('/' , 'IndexController@showIntro');
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT::  To add to this - as you know, WWW is considered a subdomain by laravel.  If you want to do something special for the "www" subdomain, you can do it within the Subdomain group.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I got some clear things from this..And if you any other way to create Multi-Tenancy in laravel 4 or any links then suggest me....Thank you

Comment: Glad to help.  If you ask the questions, I'll do my best to answer them.  We're doing something similar (though I'm going the single-database route), so I should be able to help.